# How to add PHP code inside PHP code?

Tags: php, wordpress

For example (in my case) here's some code,

```
<?php
    woo_post_inside_before();   
    if ( $woo_options['woo_post_content'] != 'content' AND !is_singular() )
        woo_image( 'width='.$woo_options['woo_thumb_w'].'&height='.$woo_options['woo_thumb_h'].'&class=thumbnail '.$woo_options['woo_thumb_align'] );
    the_title( $title_before, $title_after );
    woo_post_meta();
?>
```

Now I would like to place the following PHP code so that it's output before `woo_post_meta();`:

```
    <?php if (is_single()) : ?>
    <div class="testb"><img src="http://whatthenerd.com/what/wp-content/themes/canvas/300.jpg" alt="test Ad" /></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

If I have to show it literally, the code would be like this:

```
<?php
    woo_post_inside_before();   
    if ( $woo_options['woo_post_content'] != 'content' AND !is_singular() )
        woo_image( 'width='.$woo_options['woo_thumb_w'].'&height='.$woo_options['woo_thumb_h'].'&class=thumbnail '.$woo_options['woo_thumb_align'] );
    the_title( $title_before, $title_after );

    <?php if (is_single()) : ?>
    <div class="testthisad"><img src="http://whatthenerd.com/what/wp-content/themes/canvas/300.jpg" alt="test Ad" /></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    woo_post_meta();
?>
```

Apparently that's not the right way of doing it. So, how do I do it?

Comment: `<div class="testbitch">`? ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just have one set of tags:

```
<?php
    woo_post_inside_before();   
    if ( $woo_options['woo_post_content'] != 'content' AND !is_singular() )
        woo_image( 'width='.$woo_options['woo_thumb_w'].'&height='.$woo_options['woo_thumb_h'].'&class=thumbnail '.$woo_options['woo_thumb_align'] );
    the_title( $title_before, $title_after );

    if (is_single()){
?>
    <div class="testthisad"><img src="http://whatthenerd.com/what/wp-content/themes/canvas/300.jpg" alt="test Ad" /></div>
<?php
    }

    woo_post_meta();
?>
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy, and clear as well. Perfect example! Thanks.

Comment: @AahanKrish this is the better way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There's many ways to do it. Here's one.

```
<?php
woo_post_inside_before();   
if ( $woo_options['woo_post_content'] != 'content' AND !is_singular() )
{
     woo_image(   'width='.$woo_options['woo_thumb_w'].'&height='.$woo_options['woo_thumb_h'].'&class=thumbna il '.$woo_options['woo_thumb_align'] );
}
the_title( $title_before, $title_after );
?>
<?php if (is_single()) : ?>
    <div class="testthisad"><img src="http://whatthenerd.com/what/wp-     content/themes/canvas/300.jpg" alt="test Ad" /></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php  woo_post_meta(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want (not tested):

```
<?php
    woo_post_inside_before();   
    if ( $woo_options['woo_post_content'] != 'content' AND !is_singular() )
        woo_image( 'width='.$woo_options['woo_thumb_w'].'&height='.$woo_options['woo_thumb_h'].'&class=thumbnail '.$woo_options['woo_thumb_align'] );
    the_title( $title_before, $title_after );

    if (is_single()) : ? echo "[HTML code handling slashes]" /></div>;

    woo_post_meta();
?>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp?output=print

Comment: Turns out you can just use '[code]' instead of " which is what I meant not slashes lol. Also I edited your post for you. Cheers.....http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_echo.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<?php
// Code...
eval('my code as a string');
```

Have in mind though that's crazy dangerous.

But in your case I think you can just do

```
<?php
    woo_post_inside_before();   
    if ( $woo_options['woo_post_content'] != 'content' AND !is_singular() )
        woo_image( 'width='.$woo_options['woo_thumb_w'].'&height='.$woo_options['woo_thumb_h'].'&class=thumbnail '.$woo_options['woo_thumb_align'] );
    the_title( $title_before, $title_after );

    if (is_single()) : ?>
    <div class="testthisad"><img src="http://whatthenerd.com/what/wp-content/themes/canvas/300.jpg" alt="test Ad" /></div>
    <?php endif; 
    woo_post_meta();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But can you please use it with the example code in my question? (Noob here.)